# I need to change the color some data in the ListView rows based on value of a special column

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listview

I need to change the color some data in the ListView rows based on value of a special column. We used to do this in Row data bound event in web applications. Can i have similar function to meet this requirement in windows phone 7. Or is there any other option in wp7 to achieve this. Can any one help me in this. i am using c# as code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a DataTemplate and Binding for your ListBox?
If so, you can just bind the background of your DataTemplate's main container(eg. grid) to a property in your model.

The first answer in this question should work:-

[How to add different background colors to alternate rows to list box items windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404245/how-to-add-different-background-colors-to-alternate-rows-to-list-box-items-windo)