# Alternating row background color for ListBox rows in window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i have a ListBox in windows phone 8.0 application i want to set alternate row color of the listbox.can anybody give the full solution of the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404245/how-to-add-different-background-colors-to-alternate-rows-to-list-box-items-windo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this..

Create the ListBox in XAML

```
<ListBox Name="lstBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="{Binding Color}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Heading}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SubHeading}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then the class that used to add items to the ListBox

```
public class Items
    {
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string SubHeading { get; set; }
        public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    }
```

This Method is used to alternate the background color of the items.

```
private List<Items> AlternateColors(List<Items> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if ((list.IndexOf(item) % 2) == 0)
        {
            list[list.IndexOf(item)].Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then create the List of items and set it as the ItemsSource of the ListBox

```
List<Items> listItems = new List<Items>();
listItems.Add(new Items() {Heading =  "Heading 1", SubHeading = "Subheading 1", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });
listItems.Add(new Items() { Heading = "Heading 2", SubHeading = "Subheading 2", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });
listItems.Add(new Items() { Heading = "Heading 3", SubHeading = "Subheading 3", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });
listItems.Add(new Items() { Heading = "Heading 4", SubHeading = "Subheading 4", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });
listItems.Add(new Items() { Heading = "Heading 5", SubHeading = "Subheading 5", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });
listItems.Add(new Items() { Heading = "Heading 6", SubHeading = "Subheading 6", Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) });

lstBox.ItemsSource = AlternateColors(listItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="{Binding Back}" Width="300">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    ObservableCollection<Data> obj;
    obj = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem1", "#fdd115"));
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem2", "#3b5998"));
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem3", "#fdd115"));
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem4", "#3b5998"));
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem5", "#fdd115"));
    obj.Add(new Data("ITem6", "#3b5998"));
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = obj;
}

public class Data
{

public string Item { get; set; }
public string Back { get; set; }

public Data() { }

public Data(string Item,string Back)
{
    this.Item = Item;
    this.Back = Back;
}
}
```